# Cannot read property 'length' of undefined at MyComponent.MeteorComponent.ngOnDestroy

Tags: meteor, angular, angular2-routing, angular2-template, angular2-services

I have this error showing up when trying to go outside of MyComponent it seems to be triggered on ngOnDestroy():

```
Error: Uncaught (in promise): EXCEPTION: Error in /client/+multi-project/pm/ny-pm-tracker-details/ny-pm-tracker-details.component.html:10:12
ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
ORIGINAL STACKTRACE:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at TrackerAsideComponent.MeteorComponent.ngOnDestroy (http://localhost:3000/packages/modules.js?hash=6111b8d7b4df6b0c758550c26446f0559a271ad2:76641:55)
    at DebugAppView._View_NyPmTrackerDetailsComponent0.destroyInternal (NyPmTrackerDetailsComponent.template.js:177:35)
    at DebugAppView.AppView.destroyLocal (http://localhost:3000/packages/modules.js?hash=6111b8d7b4df6b0c758550c26446f0559a271ad2:11632:14)
    at DebugAppView.destroyLocal (http://localhost:3000/packages/modules.js?hash=6111b8d7b4df6b0c758550c26446f0559a271ad2:11767:43)
    at DebugAppView.AppView._destroyRecurse (http://localhost:3000/packages/modules.js?hash=6111b8d7b4df6b0c758550c26446f0559a271ad2:11621:14)
    at DebugAppView.AppView._destroyRecurse (http://localhost:3000/packages/modules.js?hash=6111b8d7b4df6b0c758550c26446f0559a271ad2:11619:25)
    at DebugAppView.AppView.destroy (http://localhost:3000/packages/modules.js?hash=6111b8d7b4df6b0c758550c26446f0559a271ad2:11607:14)
    at ComponentRef_.destroy (http://localhost:3000/packages/modules.js?hash=6111b8d7b4df6b0c758550c26446f0559a271ad2:10280:82)
    at RouterOutlet.unload (http://localhost:3000/packages/modules.js?hash=6111b8d7b4df6b0c758550c26446f0559a271ad2:21662:22)
    at _LoadSegments.unloadOutlet (http://localhost:3000/packages/modules.js?hash=6111b8d7b4df6b0c758550c26446f0559a271ad2:19276:24)
```

I check line 10 of mycomponent it is like this:

```
   <div class="col-sm-3">
        <th-tracker-aside                     <======This would be line 10
                [currentList]="currentList"
                (selectItem)="onSelectItem($event)">
        </th-tracker-aside>
    </div>
```

So I go to th-tracker-aside which looks like this:

```
<aside class="th-aside-list th-tracker-aside th-section-bordered animated fadeIn">
    <div class="th-aside-header-wrapper">
        <h3>Navigate by</h3>
        <select (change)="onChange($event.target.value)">
            <option *ngFor="let navItem of _trackerService.navigateByList">{{navItem}}</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="th-search-wrapper">
        <md-input>
            <span md-prefix><i class="fa fa-search th-search-icon" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
        </md-input>
    </div>
    <div class="th-aside-list-wrapper">
        <div>
            <h3>
                All {{_trackerService.navigateByLabel}} <span
                    class="th-gray-text">(#####)</span>
            </h3>
        </div>
        <ul>
            <li *ngFor="let item of _trackerService.currentList"
                (click)="changeSelectedItem(item)">
                {{item.text}}
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Everything works fine except when clicking link to go outside of view.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to have been fixed when I removed `extends MeteorComponent` from child view.